# writing a recursive function to count the depth of a tree

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I have to write a recursive function that, Given a Tree
datatype,will return the depth of the tree. An empty tree should return
0. A single root node Tree should return 1.

expected output:

```
let treeCons x = (\x -> foldl (flip insertTree) Empty x) x
depth (treeCons []) -> 0
depth (treeCons [5,4,6,3,7,1]) -> 4
depth (treeCons [1,2,5,8,9,4,7]) -> 5
depth (treeCons [5,4,6,3,7,1,2,5,8,9,4,7,8,5,3,4]) -> 6
```

I wrote the following datatype and insert function:

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Empty deriving (Show, Eq)
insertTree :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insertTree a Empty = Node a Empty Empty
insertTree a (Node b Empty Empty) = if (a <= b) then (Node b (Node a Empty Empty) Empty) else (Node b Empty (Node a Empty Empty))
insertTree a (Node b left right) = if (a <= b) then (Node b (insertTree a left) right ) else (Node b left (insertTree a right))
```

However, I'm not getting how to write depth function.I'm very new in haskell and I'll appreciate if someone helps me.

Comment: You stated the depth of an empty tree and that of a leaf. That already gives you the first two cases of your function definition (though specifying the depth for leaves is techically redundant). But what is the depth of a node with children? Once you write that down formally, it should become apparent what the last case of the function definition should be.

Comment: Note that you do not need your second case for `insertTree`; the general case `Node b left right` reduces to the base case `Empty` when the subtree you recurse on is empty.

Answer (score 4):

An empty tree has depth `0`, and a node has depth `1` plus the maximum depth of its child nodes:

```
depth :: Tree a -> Int
depth Empty = 0
depth (Node _ l r) = 1 + max (depth l) (depth r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, is very simple, recursing through a list and a Tree is about the same, only the data types differ. Where you add 1 every time you hit a branch of the tree in question:

```
tDepth :: Tree a -> Int
tDepth Empty = 0
tDepth (Node _ left right) = 1 + max (tLength left)  (tLength right)
```

Comment: That is not the depth of a tree, but the number of nodes its has.

Comment: Yep you guys where right, my bad, is fixed now although is pointless since you already gave the answer